# Sharepoint site migration SP Foundation 2010 to SP Standard 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

As per title I am looking to move an existing SP Foundation 2010 to a new SP Standard 2013 server I have setup (Both are virtual machines).

Current site - SharePoint Foundation 2010 (fairly small in size two content databases when I check in Central Admin - In our site this is WSS_Content and WSS_Content_Research size of these in SQL Server are 4GB and 16GB respectively).
Databases in background are built on SQL Server 2012 R2, these are backed up daily, no issue with space etc.

I have created a new server with appropriate specs as per technet (Sharepoint 2013 standard server).

I am looking for the most straight forward step by step methodology to move all content (hopefully with all metadata etc, with the lease possible amount of issues across to the new server instance.)

Can anyone recommend a free/reasonably priced tool that might do this? Or have a step by step guide (idiots guide would be just fine!)?

I have download Sharegate trial version and ran a copy of sites which came back with 4 red errors (these seemed fairly minor)

I have very little customized content bar a custom list (built mostly in SharePoint Designer 2010 with customized aspx - is this straight forward to move across?, it 
also has a large number of associated Workflows).
Will I need to take down the system for a short time for switching over?
Any help or advice would be HUGELY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following Links. It will help to migrate from SP 2010 to SP 2013 with very less efforts.

[SharePoint 2013 Upgrade Step by Step From SharePoint 2010](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-step-by-step-from-sharepoint-2010/)

Please make sure about the custom contents by following link if they wont work.

[Upgrading from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 Step by Step](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alimaz/2012/07/17/upgrading-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-step-by-step/)

**Notes :-**

1. You need to deploy all your custom solutions to make them work.
2. If your workflow not working than open that workflow to SharePoint designer than **Edit workflow > save without any changes > publish it** again.

& of-course, **you need to take down the SP 2010 system for a short time (Till backup the live database of SP 2010) for switching over.**

If you need further assistance than please ask here..

Comment: Upgrading is definitely not an option at this time. Is there a way to do this simply in foundation 2010? Thanks

Comment: Above given links are used to migrate the content database from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. But, as the version changes from foundation to server. you need to upgrade the database to make reference to new server's version & configuration.

Comment: Did you managed to do the migration? Have you achieved it?

Comment: All done thanks for the advice. We had very little customised content so it was mostly a case of detatching a reattaching content databases.

Comment: Glad to hear that from you at last...Happy to help you..Did you find anything helpful in my answers?